# ~/.p4enviro in ubuntu Permission denied

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, perforce, permission-denied

When I try and run ~/.p4enviro in Ubuntu
I get the following message: Permission denied

I have tried logging is as toot but that didn't help.

Comment: Why are you trying to run a config file?

Answer (score 0):

`~/.p4enviro` isn't an executable.  The permission error is because it doesn't have the `+x` permission bit set.  You can set it with `chmod +x ~/.p4enviro` but it still won't do anything useful when you try to run it.

The `P4ENVIRO` file (default `~/.p4enviro`) is used as a configuration store for the `p4 set` command: https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/p4_set.html